# AS3 / Flex mobile - Swiping list with gravity

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, swipe, gravity

Is there already a AS3/Flex solution for swiping lists (or other elements) with gravity like the app list on Android devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is not *swiping* but *scrolling*. And not *gravity* but *kinetic*. Regular Flex's Scroller component compiled under mobile theme can do that, but it sucks in many aspects (https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29734 and many others).

Comment: Thx, i'm especially looking for the item snapping feature as mentioned here (B+ Feature -> Item snapping): http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Mobile+List,+Scroller+and+Touch - Is it already implemented?

Comment: @joafeldmann I'm not fan of Flex at all, but as far as I know it's not implemented. You can try to implement it yourself via overriding the method where they calculate throw motion path. But then there will be a problem how to change scroller class in List.. that's one example of why I'm not a fan of Flex and their architecture =)

Comment: @Pavel fljot, When you tried it, it was in beta.  Have you tried with the release version of Flex 4.5? Has any fixes been added?

Comment: @J_A_X as far as I see here http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/Scroller.as key points are still not fixed/implemented

Comment: @Pavel fljot, That's not trying though ;)